# XML with reporting services namespaces enumeration yielded no result

Tags: c#, xml, linq, reporting-services, namespaces

I've got an .rdl file that obviously contains XML to generate a report.
I want to search through this XML looking for different information in the report.
The XML starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <Author>© Piet</Author>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DW_Tables">
      <DataSourceReference>DW_Tables</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>84cf022a-c58e-4286-8bc8-bca2c0358206</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
.... etc
```

Now I want all the DataSources and I use this code:

```
 var xmlnodes = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("DataSources")
                var result = from c in xmlnodes
                             select new
                             {
                                 datasource = (string)c.Element("DataSource").Value
                             };
```

This code has worked for me in numerous XML files with different namespaces
For example something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ToolsVersion="2.0">
  <DataSources>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>DW_Tables.rds</Name>
      <FullPath>DW_Tables.rds</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem>
```

But it doesn't seem to work in any way for the rdl with the reportingservices namespaces.
Every time I try to look in the descendants I get the message:      Empty   "Enumeration yielded no results"    string
"

I've tried many things but even

```
var descendants = xmlReportDoc.Root.Descendants("Reports");
```

won't give back any descendants.
I think it has something to do with the namespaces but I've got no clue what it is and how to work with it.
I've already tried declaring the namespaces in my code but this didn't seem to work either.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the elements you're struggling with are in the *default namespace*. This is denoted by the `xmlns="..."` attribute.

Use this, and you'll get some results:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"
var sources = xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "DataSources");
```

Comment: I tried that already but it didnt work before.
Because of your answer I tried it again but this time I also declared the other namespaces in the XML, even though i'm not looking through nodes using those namespaces.
That fixed my problem!! Thanks for your answer since it pushed me in the right direction :)

Comment: @Mickey I'm not sure what you mean. You don't need to 'declare' any others. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/061LKb).

Comment: I mean not only namespace;
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition");


But also:
                            
XNamespace nsrd = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner");
                            
XNamespace nscl = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/componentdefinition");

Comment: @Mickey they're all missing `http://`.... But, as the fiddle shows, you only need the namespace related to the element or elements you're looking for. I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Thats lost in my comment. Typo thing.
But i swear if i comment the other two namespaces the code fails. I will look further if im missing something then..

Comment: @Mickey just creating an `XNamespace` doesn't have any side effect as to how LINQ to XML processes queries. Are those namespaces used somewhere in your query?